# URLConnection.connect() throws a SSLKeyException for HTTPS in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, https, urlconnection

I am testing a simple method which works fine for images with the HTTP protocol, but fails for HTTPS images ONLY in eclipse. I tested in other IDEs such as DrJava and jCreator but they work fine in them. The method is as follows.

When called as follows, an exception is thrown

```
boolean verify = verifyImage("https://www.eff.org/files/HTTPS_Everywhere_new_logo.jpg");
System.out.println("Verify result is : " + verify);
```

The exception details are as follows.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available
```

The method is as follows

```
public static boolean verifyImage(String src)
 {
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
  try {
   URL url = new URL(src);
   urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   urlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");       
   urlConnection.connect();
   if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
     return true;

    } else {
     return false;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Exception");
   return false;
  }
 }
```

Any help to resolve the issue would be highly appreciated.

P.S: I tried using javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection which results in the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly the same cause as [SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872520/suntlsrsapremastersecret-keygenerator-not-available).

Try removing all of the Installed JREs from Eclipse and refinding them.