# java mail api (1.5.3) not working in recent jre1.8.25

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

im using javamail to send mail in an application. every thing works fine. but when i change the Runtime to jre1.8.25, i got exception as

```
nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2056)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:44)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
    at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:86)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:880)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:344)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:936)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:871)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:574)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:369)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2020)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:158)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:207)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(JsseJce.java:272)
    at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:77)
    ... 15 more
```

note: im using latest version of javamail api only.

Comment: Maybe you have different entries in your keyChain? As far as i know its jvm dependent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872520/suntlsrsapremastersecret-keygenerator-not-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the correct `sunjce_provider.jar` is on the classpath. If it's in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext/`, then Java should find it automatically.

See also:

- [SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872520/suntlsrsapremastersecret-keygenerator-not-available)