# Android studio Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.Cause: SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

recently i have updated my android studio to new version 2.1.and changed root project gradle build compile sdk version to 23 and build tool version to latest 23.0.3(previous it was sdk-19 and build tool-22.0.0)& in other modules like projects build.gradle,facebook,imageswipeZoom also changed them to latest.in gradle properties changed distibution url to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip. i am getting  SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available.error i dont know what should i do.if i change any thing in those places i have changed it is showing peer not authenticated error, i am new to android so please help me to fix this error, spent 3 days of time to find solutions but not found.thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872520/suntlsrsapremastersecret-keygenerator-not-available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no solutions worked(listed in the stack overflow) for me, but i found solution (@ http://tools.android.com/knownissues#TOC-peer-not-authenticated-errors-from-Gradle-sync-or-SDK-Manager) i fixed this issue by installing new jdk.(by reinstalling jdk also u can do it)