# How do I fix: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available

Tags: java, email

I am encountering a "KeyGenerator not available" error when trying to create a SSL connection using Javax.mail.

The project was functional 3-4 years ago and it was updates to JDK1.8 and to the new JRE. I assume that it's the issue is some fundamental quirk from updating the project.

I've followed everything listed [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872520/suntlsrsapremastersecret-keygenerator-not-available)

I added the path from JKD1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar to my project library so that it's both in the JRE library and the project classpath.

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:169) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(JsseJce.java:251) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:78) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
.....
```

I expected the code to create a connection at this point. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872520/suntlsrsapremastersecret-keygenerator-not-available?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that link. Yes, I've already gone over that post too

Answer (score 1):

not sure why, but this method helped me in eclipse: https://www.codetd.com/en/article/9438315

Preferences -> installed JREs -> Edit your java 8 JRE and 'Restore Defaults'

Comment: I did exactly as in your answer and got the result. Maven project compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You should update Java 8 to the current patchlevel anyway, but according to this [issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029661), you will need at least patch level 192 instead of 131. This is an issue for OpenJDK, but for Oracle Java it seems to be the same.

I assume your code was connecting to a server that has been updated to TLS 1.2 since your last usage.

Comment: It seems this problem is back with 201. Can anyone confirm?